# Proof of Hamiltonian Cycle in a Complete Bipartite Graph

Tags: graph-theory, hamiltonian-path

**A complete Bipartite graph $K_{m,n}$ has a Hamiltonian cycle if and only if $m=n$.**

I want to know if the following proof technique is correct. My proof will consider using proof by contradiction.

Assume that $m\not = n$. Let $H$ be the (Hamilton) cycle that goes through every vertex in $K_{m,n}$. $ H = v_0e_0v_1e_1...v_ie_i$. Since $K$ is bipartite, the cycle must alternate between the vertices on each side. Since $m\not = n$ there exists a $v_a = v_b, a < b$ inside cycle H. This leads to a contradiction since a cycle cannot have repeating vertices. Hence, a complete Bipartite graph $K_{m,n}$ has a Hamilton cycle if and only if $m= n$.

Is this correct?

Comment: It could be phrased a bit more clearly, but yes, you’ve proved that if there is a Hamilton cycle, then $m=n$. You’ve not proved that if $m=n$, there’s a Hamilton cycle. Admittedly, this is pretty trivial, but it does have to be addressed.

Comment: Your proof looks good. I would justify the existence of a repeated vertex using the pigeonhole principle. You also say here: "This leads to a contradiction since a cycle cannot have repeating vertices." I would note more strongly that a Hamiltonian cycle visits each vertex exactly once. It clarifies for the reader.

Comment: @BrianM.Scott How would one prove the inverse? Contradiction again? Would a direct proof be more appropriate?

Comment: Direct: just label the vertices $u_1,\ldots,u_n$ and $v_1,\ldots,v_n$ in the two parts and write down a Hamilton cycle.

Comment: And don't forget there is no Hamilton cycle if $m=n=1$.

Answer (score 2):

A complete bipartite graph $K_{m,n}$ is Hamiltonian if and only if $m = n$ , for all $m, n \geq 2$.

Proof: 
Suppose that a complete bipartite graph $K_{m, n}$ is Hamiltonian. Then, it must have a Hamiltonian cycle which visits the two partite sets alternately. Therefore, there can be no such cycle unless the two partite sets have the same number of vertices. If $m = n = 1$, it is clear that $K_{m, n}$ contains no Hamiltonian cycle.

Thus, we get $m = n$, for all $m, n \geq 2$.

Conversely, it is easy to see a Hamiltonian cycle $x_1, y_1, x_2, y_2, x_3, y_3, \dots, x_n, y_n, x_1$ for such graphs.

Answer (score 0):

Other direction can be prove in following way. As noted any cycle in bipartite graph will be of even length, and will alternate between the vertices of partite-sets. That means any Hamiltonian cycle in $K_{n,n}$ will have equal number of elements from both the partite-sets and as it covers entire vertex set, together we get $m=n$.